# Is it possible to perform nested iterations in HCL resulting in a flat list without calling flatten?

Tags: terraform, hcl

Is it possible with `HCL` to have nested iterations returning a flat `list(map)` without resorting to `flatten`?

I have this:

```
locals {
  mappings = flatten([
    for record_type in var.record_types : [
      for host in var.hosts : {
        type = record_type,
        host = host
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

I would like to remove the need for `flatten` like this:

```
locals {
  mappings = [
    for record_type in var.record_types :
      for host in var.hosts : {
        type = record_type,
        host = host
      }
    ]
}
```

But it seems like each `for .. in` must return data.

Comment: What is the benefit here of dropping flatten? The way you have it so far looks pretty clear and succinct to me.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I mean the benefit is literally to drop flatten since I don’t need the intermediary structure. It of course works as it is now.

Comment: So you want something equivalent to Python's `c = [ { first: second } for first in l1 for second in l2 ]`? I'm not sure if that's doable at all and the parser chokes at any way I see to do that. Martin Atkins (who wrote HCL2 and is very active here) will definitely be able to answer definitively though.

Comment: Indeed, the `flatten` function is the intended way to write that in the Terraform language.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative I could think of to only have a single for-loop is using `setproduct()`:

```
variable "record_types" {
  default = ["type1", "type2"]
}

variable "hosts" {
  default = ["host1", "host2"]
}

locals {
  mappings = [
    for i in setproduct(var.record_types, var.hosts) : {
      type = i[0],
      host = i[1],
    }
  ]
}

output "mappings" {
  value = local.mappings
}
```

after terraform apply resulting in:

```
Outputs:

mappings = [
  {
    "host" = "host1"
    "type" = "type1"
  },
  {
    "host" = "host2"
    "type" = "type1"
  },
  {
    "host" = "host1"
    "type" = "type2"
  },
  {
    "host" = "host2"
    "type" = "type2"
  },
]
```

Of course, the two variables need to be independent sets here.

If you want to support duplicates or have dependent inputs, `flatten()` with two loops is the way.